# Generics are not supported?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
        Map<String, String> prefMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        prefMap.put("ns2", "http://service.fr/myservice1");
        prefMap.put("ns3", "http://service.fr/myservice2");
```

And when I compile it I get the error:

```
 generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```

Comment: Generics were introduced in Java 5.

Comment: How are you compiling it? Change the compiler compliance level to at least 1.5.

Comment: I mean, it's not like the compiler didn't tell you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're compiling as Java 3, which does not support generics.

If you're using the command line, use `-source 1.5` at least.

If you're compiling with eclipse, you can change the compliance level to at least 1.5 in the settings:

> Window > Preferences and then  Java > Compiler > "Compiler compliance level"